# How to redirect and replace the input file with the output (don't erase myfile when doing "cat myfile > myfile")

Tags: bash, redirect, sh

What is the right way to redirect to a file used as input and replace the file instead of erasing the file?
I want to do something like:

```
cat myfile > myfile
```

where the program (i.e., `cat`) reads the file and then redirects to the file, so in the example above `myfile` would be unchanged.

I know that the example above will erase the file, [as explained here](http://snap.nlc.dcccd.edu/learn/madden/intro/common/redirect.html).

What is the proper syntax so the file will be replaced instead of erased?  Is stdout and redirection possible, or should the program handle opening and writing the new data to the file?  I would like to let my program send output to stdout and then the user can redirect or pipe or whatever.

BTW, I don't want to `>>` (concatenate).  I want the function on the left to write "new" data to the file -- to replace the file contents.

Perhaps a better way to state it is that I want the left side of the redirection to fully occur before the streaming occurs -- is this possible? Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of bash?

Comment: and what would be the name of your new file?

Comment: @adrin, in the example above 'myfile'

Comment: I mean, what is "new" data, if it's not "appended" data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either read all the data to memory first, or write to a temporary file and swap it out.

To read it into memory (like `vim`, `ed` and other editors do):

```
contents=$(<myfile)
cat <<< "$contents" > myfile
```

To create a temporary file (like `sed -i`, `rsync` and other updating tools do):

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp fooXXXXXX)
cat myfile > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" myfile
```

Comment: It's probably worth ensuring that `mktemp` creates its temporary file in the same directory as the original, so that the `mv` is just a rename rather than a copy-and-delete. I typically use `myfile.$$` as the intermediate file (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21492248/827263)).

Comment: @KeithThompson that's what will happen with the pattern given, without assuming that a file named `myfile.pid` never exist.

Comment: Yes -- assuming `myfile` is in the current directory. If we take the sample command literally that's not an issue, but if `myfile` is replaced by some absolute or relative pathname, it might be. You could use `$(mktemp myfileXXXXXX)`, or more generally `$(mktemp ${filename}XXXXXX)`, if `$$` isn't unique enough.

Comment: seems like `tee` might do this for you? e.g. `cat myfile | tee myfile`, from:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63824048

Comment: @Kache It's a race condition. May randomly fail for small files, always fails for large files. I left a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're interested in doing something more complex than `cat myfile`.

Some commands have command-line arguments that let you do this (typically `-i`) -- but those options work by writing to a temporary file and then renaming the temporary.

You can do the same thing yourself:

```
cat myfile > myfile.$$ && mv myfile.$$ myfile
```

I often use `$$`, which expands to my shell's process ID, as a suffix for a temporary file; it makes it fairly unlikely that the name will collide with some other file.

Using `&&` means that it won't clobber your input file unless the `cat` command succeeds.

One possible problem with this approach is that your new file `myfile.$$` is a newly created file, so it won't keep the permissions of the original input file. If you have tne GNU Coreutils version of the `chmod` command, you can avoid that problem:

```
cat myfile > myfile.$$ && \
    chmod --reference=myfile myfile.$$ && \
    mv myfile.$$ myfile
```

Comment: thanks this is good, I like the use of $$.  I will probably accept the answer from thatotherguy because he showed how to do it two ways.  But I like the use of $$, perhaps you can add that to his answer?

Comment: yes I am interested in doing something more interesting that cat :-)  I stared for hours wondering why my program would read 0 bytes when I was trying to redirect, but would print out find to stdout when I didn't redirect.  Noob mistake...

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking your question literally here. By introducing a pipe to read the output of cat, the second pipe process reads the output from stdin and redirects it to the original file name, resulting in an unchanged file:

```
cat myfile | cat - > myfile
```

DANGER: This is a race condition. There is no guarantee that the first process can read the entire comments of myfile before the second process truncates it with the output redirection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In my particular case, I am already using stdin for another purpose (basically information to add the the file in a "special" way).  However, this may be of use in the future, and it did answer the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* that's 100% reliable? Race conditions can have surprising results.

Comment: If this worked, congratulations, you won the race condition. There is no guarantee that the first process can read the entire comments of `myfile` before the second process truncates it with the output redirection.

Comment: [Reposting the previous comment from 2014-02-01 and removing a broken link]: Apart from any other problems, the `-` is unnecessary; `cat` by itself is equivalent to `cat -` (`cat` reads from `stdin` if you don't specify any file names). The `-` argument is useful if you want to concatenate the contents of `stdin` *and* one or more files. (Useless use of hyphen?)