# Output redirection to the same file without a temporary file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

Let's say I have a tab-delimited data file. I would like to convert every tab in the file to a single space character.

```
$ cat junk
John Doe    35  New York
Bob Smith   24  Boston
Jane Doe    31  Los Angeles
```

To do that, I can use the `expand` command. If I do it like this:

```
$ expand -t 1 junk > junk
```

it will clobber the junk file and all the data will be lost. The simplest solution that comes to mind is, of course, redirect the output to a temporary file and then redirect the output from the temporary file back to the original one. That would look something like this:

```
$ expand -t 1 junk > temp
$ cat temp > junk
$ rm temp
$ cat junk
John Doe 35 New York
Bob Smith 24 Boston
Jane Doe 31 Los Angeles
```

I think this is too much hassle. Maybe there's a simpler way that I could use to do the whole thing in one go?

Comment: It is the simplest way. You can read the entire file into an array or something similar, process it in the memory, and write back to the same file. But it would be much more hassle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect without erasing file cat myfile > myfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492189/how-to-redirect-without-erasing-file-cat-myfile-myfile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU sed (the question is tagged `linux` so that probably is the case), you can use its `-i` or `--in-place` option which deletes its temporary files (unless you provide a backup suffix).

Use the `s` (substitute) command to replace each tab with a space; the `g` (global) modifier replaces all tab characters on the line being processed, i.e., not just the first tab character:

```
sed -i 's/\t/ /g' junk
```

Comment: This answers the specific part of the question as the generalised form is a duplicate.