# How to redirect output from into a file with values without clearing the file?

Tags: shell

I am looking for a command line that would run the line below and send the output into a file with a for each. I'm not sure what command would work since I thought the > and < were the main commands for redirecting input and output.

```
cat ls -1 *.B sed -e 's/\.B$//' | awk '{print $1,"\\"}'>name.dat
```

Then I want the output of to go into a file with a foreach.

```
name1\
name2\
name3\
```

The directed file would look like this.

```
foreach(\

)
```

In the end, I would like the file to look like this.

```
foreach(\
name1\
name2\
name3\
)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `tee` instead of redirection.

For example, the following command line would reverse a file without **clearing** it, just like **touching**:

`cat foo.txt | sort -r | tee foo.txt`

A simpler case, you can just **refresh** a file without changing any of its content:

`cat foo.txt | tee foo.txt`

After this, all that happened was changing the file's modification time.

Use `tee -a` to append to a file instead of overwriting it.

That's just the answer for your case.

Comment: This is a race condition. It may or may not work for small files depending on whether `cat` or `tee` is scheduled first. `cat foo.txt | tee foo.txt` will never work for larger files, because `cat` will eventually pause to wait for `tee foo.txt` to run. There's a utility `sponge` that can be used instead.